# Is there somewhere I can see a diverse range of plating options?

Tags: presentation, plating

I'm not very good at plating, but I'm okay at copying ways that other chefs have plated their foods. I recently watched [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=myH-i3-hWCE) where two chefs make and plate a dish, and then compare their results to those done by students at a culinary school.

Is there a website that shows a variety of plating options for the same recipe? I realize I can just do a Google image search for the name of the dish, but ideally I want to be looking at the exact same recipe in all pictures, and a reasonably high caliber of presentation.

Comment: I think google image search will be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The Art of Plating is pretty good. They have a website, but I recommend their twitter feed.

Other than that, I would refer to plain google searches. Cookbooks are good inspiration. I think that amongst books, Essential Cuisine is supposed to be one of the better ones for plating (albeit I don't think you would go wrong with something like The Fat Duck Cookbook or Noma: Time and Place in Nordic Cuisine).